# Why is app launch showing frameworks that I did not include in the app?

Tags: xcode, macos, diagnostics

In my Objective-C app, I am only linking `libreadline.tbd` as the binary. On launch, I am getting the below log, which shows `Kerberos`, `WebKit`. Are these included in my app? Why are these shown when it is not included?

Also `126687488.8 seconds` for binding time looks wrong, or am I misinterpreting?

```
Total pre-main time:   0.39 milliseconds (100.0%)
         dylib loading time:  29.29 milliseconds (7342.3%)
        rebase/binding time: 126687488.8 seconds (151510788.2%)
            ObjC setup time:  14.44 milliseconds (3620.2%)
           initializer time:  41.54 milliseconds (10413.6%)
           slowest intializers :
             libSystem.B.dylib :  14.07 milliseconds (3528.1%)
   libBacktraceRecording.dylib :   3.91 milliseconds (981.8%)
                libc++.1.dylib :   0.01 milliseconds (4.1%)
                CoreFoundation :   0.55 milliseconds (139.5%)
                     CFNetwork :   0.01 milliseconds (3.5%)
                    Foundation :   0.28 milliseconds (71.1%)
    libMainThreadChecker.dylib :  13.74 milliseconds (3446.1%)
                        vImage :   0.39 milliseconds (98.2%)
                      CoreText :   0.03 milliseconds (7.6%)
                      Kerberos :   0.83 milliseconds (209.3%)
                   CoreDisplay :   0.39 milliseconds (98.0%)
                      FaceCore :   0.01 milliseconds (2.7%)
         libFosl_dynamic.dylib :   0.30 milliseconds (75.3%)
                     CoreImage :   0.06 milliseconds (15.2%)
                        AppKit :   0.09 milliseconds (23.6%)
                   QuickLookUI :   5.23 milliseconds (1313.1%)
             libprotobuf.dylib :   0.13 milliseconds (32.7%)
           WirelessDiagnostics :   0.01 milliseconds (2.7%)
                        WebKit :   0.01 milliseconds (3.3%)
  libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib :   0.99 milliseconds (249.9%)
                        CoreML :   0.00 milliseconds (2.1%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are included with your IOS app by default. It is just daemons in your app basically